# Why is "ita vero" two words?

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice, spoken-language

I was taught the way to say "yes" in Latin is two words: "ita vero". It seems counter-intuitive that it's two words, but why is that so? In essence, why is the Latin word for yes two words? Does "ita" mean something by itself and "vero" mean something by itself and somehow "ita vero" means yes?
~M.C.

Comment: As an aside, the Italian and Spanish (and to an extent French) “si” come from “sic” (thus) while French “oui”
Comes via a roundabout route from “hoc ille” (thus he). It seems that Latin had quite a few affirmative idioms.

Comment: In French, the old language used  "Si fait"; "Oui da" , etc... So the 2 words "yes" is not so uncommon. "Si" or "Oui" would have been enough, but it's more emphatic.

Answer (score 9):

Latin does not have a word "yes".
There are other ways to express the same idea, like the English "exactly", "indeed", "very much so", and so on.
From an English point of view, you need some kind of a circumlocution to say "yes" in Latin.

The common translation *ita vero* means "truly so".
I would not say that this pair of words is yes, but that it can be used to convey the same message.
Depending on context, you might say *ita*, *est*, *consentio*, *volo*, or something else.
Thinking of *ita vero* as a direct and accurate translation of "yes" is misleading.

Answer (score 6):

In the English phrases
"Even so," "More so," or (historical) "Exactly so," 'so' = *ita*

> ***Ita*** (adverb) so, thus,in this way.
>   (and also by itself)
>   ***ita*** **C.** In affirmations, esp. in replies, yes, it is so, just so, true: quid istic tibi negoti est? Dav. Mihin'? Si. Ita, **[Lewis & Short *TUFTS*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DI%3Aentry%20group%3D78%3Aentry%3Dita)**

Where a bald and unconvincing monosyllable requires extra emphasis
*ita certe*
*ita vero*
*ita est*
*ita profecto*
and *ita plane,* 'clearly yes,' can be found in comedies and orations.

...and *vero* also, adverb from ***[vērus , a, um,](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=v%C4%93rus&la=la&can=v%C4%93rus0)*** adj. (=true, real, actual) can also mean 'Yes,' by itself

> **B.** *vērō* , in truth, in fact, certainly, truly, to be sure, surely, assuredly:
>   **b. In corroborative replies,** yes, certainly, by all means, assuredly, etc. (class.; while verum in this sense is only ante-class.): De. *An quid est etiam amplius?* He. *Vero amplius,* '...even more?' 'Yes, more.'(Terence)